# Allow only one userid to login at a time?

Tags: linux

Would there be a way to only allow one userid to log into a Linux system via ssh at a time?  That one userid should be able to open additional connections via ssh to the server.

There would also need to be a way to allow any user a mechanism to boot out the logged in user, if necessary.

Comment: ***WHY*** (in the name of everything holy) would you want this? What practical real-world problem in a production environment are you trying to solve?

Comment: It's a custom application that allows modification of its configuration via multiple utilities.  We would like to limit the users so that backing up of configuration and a possible subsequent restore would not be overwritten by multiple users.  We could use policy to enforce this, but I wanted to see if there was a technical solution.

Comment: Couldnt you do something with extended attributes like immutable, or even using the sticky bit?

Comment: It's not a single file.  It's an entire suite of utilities and applications.

Answer (score 8):

The only robust way to do what you're asking is a custom [PAM module](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_authentication_module) that checks to see if other users are logged in, and denies access if that is the case.

If you implement such a disgusting solution to protect a configuration file You're *DOING IT **WRONGEST***.
You want [file locking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking), not nonstandard hackery that breaks the very underlying model of Unix (multi-user time-sharing system) and tramples all over the [principle of least astonishment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

Comment: I'm not protecting a specific configuration file otherwise it would have been simple.  I need to protect the entire system as many utilities and applications access multiple configuration files.

Comment: I was thinking a PAM module, but was wondering if something was already available that I might take advantage of.

Comment: Since it seems we are allowed to include belittling comments that don't answer the question, I'll rebuttal your statement about 'DOING IT WRONGEST'.  This is a custom application that happens to be running on a Linux system.  I'm not interested in the 'principle of least astonishment' nor multi-user ability as this is again, a custom application.

I can see where that would be appropriate for a general purpose server, but this is not.

Comment: @BlackNovaYZFR1 I stand by my statement. In my professional opinion your proposed solution is a terrible idea, and there's no good reason for it when you can accomplish your stated goal with proper engineering and mutexes/locking rather than the hack you're proposing to use. If you truly feel my comments are out of line feel free to flag the post, and I will leave the flag for another moderator to deal with.

Comment: There's no need for belittling comments. Especially in corporate environments, sometimes one needs to work with a system that is horrible, but it can't be changed, only worked around. I have a use case where a similar solution would help.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit number of simultaneous connections on IP level too, like this:

> iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn --dport 22 -m connlimit --connlimit-above 1 -j REJECT

It's not a very good method (connections might break till timeout value), but might work for you.

And this won't force logout of other user.

Globally - bad idea, you may terminate something important.

Comment: This still has all the negative effects of restricting SSH access though (i.e. "The sysadmin can't get in to fix something if it's really broken", "One rogue user going to lunch without logging out can DoS the environment")...

Comment: yeah, ugly thing, it's enough just to telnet to the port 22, without logging, while tcp connection will be up.

Comment: That wouldn't allow the same user to open multiple connections.